# Restart Azure postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, azure, cloud

I have to change the

```
max_prepared_transactions
```

setting in azure what require a restart or reload config.
Unfortunately I can not restart the postgresql database because Azure doesn't support it.

I try to run

```
 SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

command but I get the following error

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to signal the postmaster
```

But Im using the database admin user what I set.

What can I do??

Comment: Yes. "Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers" service. 
I created a database inside of that.

Comment: Here is what showing in the log file.

2018-01-24 09:56:40 UTC-5a61f378.101c-LOG:  parameter "max_prepared_transactions" cannot be changed without restarting the server
2018-01-24 09:56:40 UTC-5a61f378.101c-LOG:  configuration file "/pgdata/postgresql.auto.conf" contains errors; unaffected changes were applied

Comment: Do you change parameter via Azure portal? I change it via Azure portal, it works for me.

Comment: Azure now lets you restart the database. It's a button at the top of the overview page of the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change he parameter it will be not accept on the database. The GUI will show the new value but the database wont running on that.The only one solution what I found is to scale the database to other amount of Compute Unit and after back. This operation trigger a config reload under the hood in Azure

Comment: Confirmed, I have the same. There is something that creeps up the memory slowly, but incrementally. I have no access to the instance, so I need to restart the service (which is not possible in Azure). So, I've setup an Azure Alert that informs me every time the memory exceeds >80%, which happens roughly every month, then I scale up the instance - and a couple of hours later I scale it down. #poor-mans-solution

Answer (score 2):

You can't restart that service, that service managed by Azure.

I had update that parameter `max_prepared_transactions` via Azure portal, it works for me:

[image]

Please try to update it via Azure portal, hope this helps.

More information about [configure server parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-configure-server-parameters-using-portal), please refer to this article.

Comment: Hello. If you change he parameter it will be not accept on the database. 
The GUI will show the new value but the database wont running on that.The only one solution what I found is to scale the database to other amount of Compute Unit and after back. This operation trigger a config reload under the hood in Azure.